# How to set full screen video on button click in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-video-player

I am using [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) in [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) and I am playing video in TextureView. I have a button in Fragment and want to play video in full screen the button is clicked. It is possible in Fragment because I am using Fragment in an Activity.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What about if you create another activity or fragment displaying a video in full screen and you just call an Intent when button is pressed

Comment: i have tried that idea but video does not start from last position new activity will start from begining.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, `before setContentView()`

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
//Now you have a full screen view of an activity
```

if you are changing orientation of your phone from Portrait to Landscape, then add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in Activity tag `Manifest.xml`, then in code do the following

```
private int oldOptions;

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        oldOptions = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
        int newOptions = oldOptions;
        newOptions &= ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE;
        newOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        newOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        newOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;
        newOptions &= ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newOptions);
        getActionBar().hide();
    }
    else
    {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(oldOptions);
        getActionBar().show();
    }
}
```

Comment: sir i am using fragment in activity , my video is playing like instagram , but i have a button on that video for full screen functionality but i am not getting right way to do this task.

Comment: then you have to set fragment layout programatically.

Comment: but i have a problem with that..when i set fragment layout programatically video play from begining not from last position.

Comment: sir, i want to know that is it possible with textureview or should i use video view?